# Does a $\sigma$-algebra generated by an uncountable number of RVs exist?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables

In Evan's Introduction to Stochastic Differential Equations", it says

> **Definition.** Let $X(\cdot)$ be a real-valued stochastic process. Then
> $$ \mathcal{U}(t) := \mathcal{U}(X(s)\vert 0\le s \le t), $$
> the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the random variables $X(s)$ for $0 \le s \le t$, is called the history of the process until (and including) time $t \ge 0$.

However, does a $\sigma$-algebra generated by an infinite number of random variables exist? What I know is there exists a $\sigma$-algebra generated by a countable number of random variables. Do we need an axiom of choice to construct this $\sigma$-algebra?

Any help or any reference would be appreciated!

Comment: It's just the intersection of every $\sigma$-algebra $F$ such that $\mathcal{U}(t)$ is $F$-measurable for every $t$. That's also the definition in the countable case. You don't need choice or anything like that for this to be a well-defined object.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou I see. Is there at least one $\sigma$-algebra where all $X(s)$, $0 \le s \le t$, are measurable? The original one...?

Comment: Or the trivial power-set $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Thank you very much!